# showing districts limited areas by polygon in google map in R

Tags: r, google-maps

In google map, some specific districts have a determined limited area. I have the list of these districts and their lat-lon in the city of Tehran. for example, if you search "بهارستان" you will have something like:[image]

in R, how can I show many of polygons of districts like this on a map with different colors?

Comment: http://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html

Comment: search for "choropleth maps"

Comment: @xomena it's not clear if this is an exact duplicate, because the question is about the implementation in R.

Comment: My point is you cannot get boundaries via Google Maps APIs. Doesn't matter which programming language you use.

Comment: how did you find these limited areas?!For example for baharestan